# Javascript Closure Keeps Returning a Function But Should Be a String

Tags: javascript, function, object, closures

I have written the following closure that should return a string but it returns a function object. What am I doing wrong here?

```
BDS.CDNS = (function() {

var DEVROOT;
var TESTROOT = '/';
var PRODROOT = '/';
var _IsSecure;

return {
    CDN1: function CDN1() {
        if (BDS.ENV === BDS.ENV_OPTIONS.DEV) {
            return (_IsSecure ? BDS.SECUREPROTOCOL : BDS.UNSECUREPROTOCOL) + DEVROOT;
        }
        else if (BDS.ENV === BDS.ENV_OPTIONS.TEST) {
            return (_IsSecure ? BDS.SECUREPROTOCOL : BDS.UNSECUREPROTOCOL) + TESTROOT;
        }
        else if (BDS.ENV === BDS.ENV_OPTIONS.PROD) {
            return (_IsSecure ? BDS.SECUREPROTOCOL : BDS.UNSECUREPROTOCOL) + PRODROOT;
        }
        return '';
    }
}());
```

When calling BDS.CDNS.CDN1 => function object. It should return a string.

Thanks.

Comment: `BDS.CDNS.CDN1()` maybe?

Comment: it will return a string.... once you execute it.

Comment: Looks a bit like [JCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Control_Language#Complexity) to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reference `BDS.CDNS.CDN1`, you're getting a function object, because it is a function. In order to execute this function you need to include parenthesis:

```
BDS.CDNS.CDN1();
```

Comment: Kenneth, you are 100% correct. I wish there was a remote central nervous system trigger that produces pain for STUPID oversights. You have my permission to pull it and shock me! Thanks chief!